# how to show firebase analystics in flutter app screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

hi there if my app connected with Firebase and i have another admin app

is there a way to display number of users and which screen they entered and else

or any analytics from Firebase to my app screen or not

Comment: any help in it !?

Comment: *is there a way*? Yes there is! Show us the code you've attempted, explain your troubleshooting and we'll see if we can spot the issue. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)